# How to use Oauth 2.0 Authorization in Logic App's HTTP connector

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-logic-apps

There is an API that I need to iteratively return data from in an Azure Logic App. To do this I need two HTTP steps, 1 to receive an access token and the other to use the token to be returned the data. Unfortunately, I can only receive the token through Oauth 2.0 Authorization and Azure Logic App does NOT have that authorization feature built into the connector (But I see Active Directory OAuth which seems different). Is there any way around this?

**Trying to achieve the below. But the only concern I have is with Step 2: Logic doesn't have Oauth 2.0 Authorization**

[image]

**The available OAuth Authentication option is OAuth Active Directory which is specific to Azure and my requirement is for an external URL which only has client Id & client secret information**

[image]
[image]

**Tried below. Getting error**
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? They’re just headers or parameters through the body in the call so yes, it does support it.

Comment: Hi Skin, I have updated my question to include what I have tried

Comment: It’s actually really hard to give you a definitive answer because I can’t test a solution for you unless I know the platform and even then, unless I can sign up for a free trial or something, I may not be able to validate a solution.

Comment: If you have a look at the screenshot you provided, it's pretty much telling you what to do, it has the JSON and says that you need to make a `POST` call to get a token so have you tried that?  Throw that in the body and see what happens.

Comment: Tenant & Audience is mandatory here and this is only available for a service on Azure. I have tried to use other available authentication options but nothing works

Comment: No, paste the JSON into the body and call it manually.  It's just a HTTP call, you're not understanding what I am saying.  If you can do it in postman, you do it the same here.  What's the service?  I'll get it to work.  You provided some documentation on authorisation above, just follow that.  Ignore the auth section in the HTTP action, use the body and call it as you would from any application.  Get it to work in Postman first and you'll be good.

Comment: Stop fixating on the `Authentication` section and construct it as you would in a normal sense.

Comment: I updated my http request to include all below and when I ran I got 'Unable to parse request'

URI = https://adfae.adfa.asd/auth/token
Headers = Content-Type application/json
Body = grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<>&client_secret=<>

Comment: Then show us that in a screenshot or something.

Comment: Updated to include the screenshot

Comment: You haven't wrapped it in JSON and you've specified JSON as the content-type AND it's what's in your screenshot at the top so structure it as JSON and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic app DOES have the Authorization feature built into the http connector. Click on the Add new parameter dropdown.

[image]

But this is for specific cases. In your case the credentials are in the body so you can use the native connector without any Authorization. Just add the headers and body that you need as below.
[image]

The body I used is like below (to match your body requirements):

{"client_id":"@{triggerBody()?['client_id']}","client_secret":"@{triggerBody()?['client_secret']}","grant_type":"client_credentials"}

If successful, You will need to parse the response so you can use the token from the response in the next actual call to the API.

Comment: There is authentication, but the available option is OAuth Active Directory, which is specific to Azure. I'm trying to create a token for an external URL. Do you know how this can be done?